# Woocommerce: Filter Products by Rating, STARS has no shades color

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I'm trying to create a custom interface for the filters of my shop, one of them is `Filter Products by Rating` which is I added through `ShortCode` using the class of [WC_Widget_Rating_Filter](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Widget_Rating_Filter.html) with the help of [Elementor](https://elementor.com/) and ShortCode widget.

[image]

Unfortunately, there are no shades of gold color in the stars.

I tried to add the Widget by navigating into `Appearance` > `Widgets` and drag it into `Woocommerce SideBar` which where I want to show the widget, here is the result.

[image]

For some reason, the one I added through ShortCode has no shades of gold color while the one I added by navigating into `Appearance` > `Widgets` and dragging it into `Woocommerce SideBar` has a color and is working properly.

What could be the reason for it and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi. You'll have to include your code, rather than some screen shots of what isn't working, so people can help you.

Comment: @HowardE - There is no code. Like I said I made the whole thing using drag and drop with the help of Elementor. Using Elementor to create my custom filter view, I just drag the widget `ShortCode` and input the class of `WC_Widget_Rating_Filter`, it works, however, there are no shades of gold color in the stars. When I tried to add the `Filter Products by Rating` by navigating into `Appearance` > `Widget` then drag it to the Woocommer SideBar, it works. I think the issue is related to the CSS but I wasn't able to figure it out.

Comment: Did you tried asking this in Wordpress forum support for Woocommerce? https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce/

Comment: @Polar -  I did, but no luck. I notice that their support is barely responding, there are so many questions and most of them are ignored or unsolved.